# Test goodness of fit for weighting samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

There are N samples $x_1, x_2, ...,x_N$ for random variable $X$.

I know [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) can be used to figure whether X follows uniform distribution.

First, discretize the range of $X$ and get $M$ classes. Then calculate
$\chi^2=\sum\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$ where $O_i$ is the number of samples belonging to class $i$, and $E_i$ equals to $\frac{N}{M}$. Finally compare $\chi^2$ to the critical value from the chi-squared distribution with $m-1$ degrees of freedom.

However, what if the samples are weighted. Say, $X$'s PDF is $p(x)$, and there is a weight function for the samples, and $f(x_1), f(x_2)..., f(x_N)$ are known. I want to know whether $p(x)f(x)$ is a uniform distribution. The original problem is a special case of this problem where $f(x_i) \equiv 1$.

Can chi-squared test be used in this problem? Or any other solutions?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. Let $Y=f(X)$ and $y_i=f(x_i)$. You want to known if the $y_i$ follow a uniform distribution. The $\chi^2$ test will work on $y_i$. But note that's not a weighted sample, and the original problem would have $f(x)=x$, not $f(x)=1$. Maybe you have something else in mind?

Comment: For a really weighted sample, there is a way using Rao-Scott correction, see [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyfreq_details50.htm) or [this](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/svychisq.html) for a few explanations and references.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  I edit the question. Does Rao-Scott chi-squared test work in this case? By the way, I read the link above and some papers about Rao-Scott correction roughly and confused by some notations. There seem to be several different Rao-Scott corrections, right?